# Magento 2.1.1- i18n:collect-phrases not working

Tags: magento-2.1, error, localisation, create

I tried to create a translation dictionary for my whole magento site by using the following command:

```
php magento i18n:collect-phrases -o '/var/www/html/kikinben2/app/i18n/alothemes/bn_bd/bn_BD.csv' -m
```

I got this error:

```
[DomainException]  
Missed phrase
```

It works only when I try with a directory path instead of `-m` at the end. But I need to make it for the whole website, not for a single module.

Comment: Hi, I also use this version of magento and some translations on checkout are not working. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

REASON for it are __('') ? in third-party extension (or in design theme).

to find empty strings

grep -rnw . -e "**('')" -e '**("")'

not only "empty strings" give that error but __('0'); also fails.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this on a Magento 2.3.7 site, when trying use translations to alter text like "Jot us a note" on the contact us page.

When I used that grep command to find the issues, it came back with just 2 results, both from the dev tools:
./dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Model/Address/CreateAddressTest.php:480:                    'request_message' => __(''),
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Customer/Model/Address/CreateAddressTest.php:480:                    'request_message' => __(''),

So not sure how best to fix?